# How to draw a graph with less crossing by using some broken line?

Tags: algorithm, graph, drawing

I'm dealing with a graph with n nodes' coordinate and m undirected edges, how can I get a better visual graph(with less crossing) by allow using some broken line instead of straight line?

I know minimize the crossing number is a NP problem. So I just ask for some help here beacuse I think someone may give me some resources about it.

What's more, I think it is ok that change some nodes' coordinate(not move them too far), all in all, it's the problem that how to find a more clear graph for our eyes!

Answer (score 0):

[GraphViz website](http://www.graphviz.org/) is a good place to start learning about graph visualization.

Answer (score 0):

The [Boost graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/) (i.e. BGL) has plenty of algorithms and data structures to experiment with, and a dual interface (c++ of course, or python). Of course, Boost isn't the easiest way to start. Surely Graphviz (that BGL can interface) it's way simpler.

In the [BGL docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_graphs.html) there are many resource you could find useful: for instance, from the previous link:

> Any plane drawing separates the plane into distinct regions bordered by graph edges called faces. As a simple example, any embedding of a triangle into the plane separates it into two faces: the region inside the triangle and the (unbounded) region outside the triangle. The unbounded region outside the graph's embedding is called the outer face. Every embedding yields one outer face and zero or more inner faces. A famous result called Euler's formula states that for any planar graph with n vertices, e edges, f faces, and c connected components,
>
> n + f = e + c + 1
>
> This formula implies that any planar graph with no self-loops or parallel edges has at most 3n - 6 edges and 2n- 4 faces. Because of these bounds, algorithms on planar graphs can run in time O(n) or space O(n) on an n vertex graph even if they have to traverse all edges or faces of the graph.
>
> A convenient way to separate the actual planarity test from algorithms that accept a planar graph as input is through an intermediate structure called a planar embedding. Instead of specifying the absolute positions of the vertices and edges in the plane as a plane drawing would, a planar embedding specifies their positions relative to one another. A planar embedding consists of a sequence, for each vertex in the graph, of all of the edges incident on that vertex in the order in which they are to be drawn around that vertex. The orderings defined by this sequence can either represent a clockwise or counter-clockwise iteration through the neighbors of each vertex, but the orientation must be consistent across the entire embedding.
>
> In the Boost Graph Library, a planar embedding is a model of the PlanarEmbedding concept. A type that models PlanarEmbedding can be passed into the planarity test and populated if the input graph is planar. All other "back end" planar graph algorithms accept this populated PlanarEmbedding as an input. '